# Can't connect android emulator to look at local sites and services

Tags: tomcat, android

I'm trying to use an Android emulator to use services running on my local machine. I have a site running under IIS which in my host file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       www.local.company.co.uk
```

I have several sites running under Apache Tomcat. My host file for Tomcat related sites:

```
127.0.0.1       internal.localhost.company.com  # port:8090
127.0.0.2       external.localhost.company.com  # port:8081
127.0.0.3       auth.ws.localhost.company.com  # port:8082
127.0.0.8       mysite.localhost.company.com  # port:8086
```

What I have tried so far (in the following steps):

```
adb pull /etc/hosts
```

Edit Android host file:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
10.0.2.2         myefc.localhost.efinancialcareers.com

adb remount
adb push hosts /etc/hosts
```

Then I try to visit myefc.localhost.efinancialcareers.com in the browser and am told webpage not found. I’d at least expect it to go to www.local.company.co.uk.

What I would ideally like is to be able to go to any site on my local machine which are specified in the above host file examples.

I am on Windows 7 and using Tomcat 6. The emulator I am using is nexus one.

Comment: I've been told here that this maybe a networking issue - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37310/cant-connect-android-emulator-to-look-at-local-sites-and-services

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read this arcticle: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

'Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service that isolates it from your development machine's network interfaces and settings and from the internet. An emulated device can not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall."

There are some recommendation in there for advanced networking.